# What to do if I get refunded by my 401k for being considered HCE?

Tags: united-states, 401k, ira, retirement, excess-contribution

If my employer gives back some of the money I put away on my 401k because I am considered a HCE, can I turn around and put it back into an IRA to avoid paying taxes and penalties that year? I am over 50.

Comment: Yes, provided you're not over the IRA deductibility limit as well.

Comment: Good answer Joe, why not make it an answer so I can upvote ya?

Comment: "avoid paying taxes and penalties" Why would you have penalties?

Comment: @user102008 There could be underwithholding if the extra 401(k) contributions are returned without taxes being taken out.

Comment: Consider asking this question to your payroll department and/or the institution that holds your IRA.  Likely they both have experts in this area.

Comment: Note that if you get refunded for excess contributions, it usually happens in the following year, in which case it doesn't affect the year where these contributions occured -- rather, the refund counts as taxable income in the year you received the refund.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, provided you're not over the IRA deductibility limit as well. –  JoeTaxpayer♦ Aug 4 at 18:02

Note that if you get refunded for excess contributions, it usually happens in the following year, in which case it doesn't affect the year where these contributions occured -- rather, the refund counts as taxable income in the year you received the refund. –  user102008 Aug 11 at 8:11